# Not sure if I'm creating a correct lifetime scope

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, specflow, lifetime-scoping

One of my Specflow steps is trying to use a method which takes Autofac's `ILifetimeScope` as a parameter. This is the method the step is trying to call:

```
public Client(string clientAddress, ILogger<Client> logger, IFieldDict fieldDict, IdGenerator idGenerator, ILifetimeScope scope);
```

I don't use Autofac in my Specflow application so am not sure if I'm creating the `ILifetimeScope` correctly.

I added this to my constructor but am not sure if it's the correct thing to do but my client instance doesn't seem to be getting created correctly.

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
container = (Container)containerBuilder.Build();
var lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("KEY");
_iLifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
```

Can anybody advise what I might need to do here?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to register all the dependencies that the `Client` is resolving from the `ILifetimeScope` before creating the scope and passing it to the `Client` constructor.

For example, if the `Client` is resolving an `IService` dependency, you could create a mock of this dependency and register it in the container:

```cs
var serviceMock = new Mock<IService>();
containerBuilder.RegisterInstance(serviceMock.Object);

var container = containerBuilder.Build();
var lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope();
```

You can then pass the `lifetimeScope` instance to the `Client` constructor.

This example is assuming that you are using [moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) to mock your services. Passing a `KEY` to the `BeginLifetimeScope` method is usually not required.

However, depending on how the `ILifetimeScope` is used in the `Client`, building the container may be more complicated. It is usually discouraged to inject a `ILifetimeScope` directly, the required services should be injected instead. There are a lot of ways to inject more complex services, so injecting the `ILifetimeScope` is usually not required (see [Named and Keyed Services](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html), [Delegate Factories](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html) and [Owned Instances](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/owned-instances.html)).

[AutoMock](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/moq.html) may also be worth a look, it simplifies creating objects with a lot of dependencies, as you don't have to mock every dependency individually.